# How to allow to edit field in django admin list depending on a value?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I need to allow to change a value of a field if it doesn't equal to 0.
I found that I need to override `get_changelist_form` but don't know how.

I tried to override form but it raised `Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form OrderChangeListForm needs updating.`

What I need:

```
def get_changelist_form(self, request, **kwargs):
  # if instance.status == 0 make it not editable
  return super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_changelist_form(request, **kwargs)
```

My Model:

```
class ModelAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ['id', 'client', 'status']
    list_editable = ('status',)
```

Comment: is it typo? you should have MyModelAdmin in admin.py, right?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use has_change_permission method in admin

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import YourModel

class YourModel(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj: YourModel= YourModel):
        if obj.num == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True

admin.site.register(YourModel, YourModelAdmin)
```

just change YourModel with your model name

note: if your status field type is string(like CharField), you must replace:

```
if obj.num == 0:
```

with:

```
if obj.num == '0':
```

Comment: I need to have a possibility to limit change permission for some instances on django model view list